# div overflow-x child resizes with parent container width

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a `1100px-width` div general container which I'd call (A) that resizes to `925px` in my aplication. In addition, I have a div which has to more divs inside: one has a static width (`200px`) which I'd call (B) and the other doesn't but has an horizontal scrollbar which I'd call (C).

[image]

I want when general container resizes (A) , the div (C) resizes,too and keep its scroll bar.

I have came up with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikegohome/eeLgp5gL/1/) so far but I can't figure it out what I am doing wrong.

*Pd: I have used different metrics for simulatio*n.

**¿How can I make the div child(C) resizes with general container(A) width?**

.

[image]

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I've tried to be more specific this time. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its latest update 
**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/966naq5e/2/)**

```css
html {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}
.container{
    height:100px;
}
.left{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:green;
    float: left;
}
.right{
    overflow-x:auto;
    background-color:red;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
}
.content{
    width:600px;
    position :relative;
}
.wrap{
   overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="right">
           <div class="content">
                CONTENT   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, it's great. (C) keep resizing; however It is necessary that (C) is beside (B), not under.

Answer (score 0):

(C) should not resize, but have a certain width (more than 900px, to get the scrollbar.).  The container (A) does the resizing and should have min-width:925px

**update:**
it turned out to be a bit more complex: 
http://jsfiddle.net/p7perzc6/

```
.a {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    width : 800px;
    height: 200px;
}
.b {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: green;   
     height: 200px;
    float: left;
}
.c {        
    background-color: orange;
 height: 200px;
    margin-left: 101px;
    float: left; 
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 900px;
    position: fixed;        
}
```

Comment: Could you please make a jsfidle to  see how it works?

Comment: you actually have 2 `width` settings for class `.c`